# Use a beginWith or startWith filter in a graphQL query with Gatsby

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby, graphql-js

Following Gatsby tutorial here https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/adding-tags-and-categories-to-blog-posts/ it is possible to filter posts by tag to create tag pages easily...

What I'm trying to achieve is to create index pages for posts having the same slug prefx :

- /folder1/sub1/post-A
- /folder1/sub1/post-B
- /folder1/sub2/post-C

Will create 3 index pages :

- /folder1/ (containing the three posts)
- /folder1/sub1/ (containing post A and B)
- /folder1/sub2/ (containing only post C)

This will use a query like :

```
export const query = graphql`
  query tagListQuery($prefix: String, $skip: Int!, $limit: Int!) {
    allMarkdownRemark(
      sort: { fields: [frontmatter___date], order: DESC }
      filter: { fields: { slug: { startsWith: $prefix } } }
      limit: $limit
      skip: $skip
    ) {
      edges {
        node {
          id
          frontmatter {
            title
          }
          fields {
            slug
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

But `startsWith` filtering does not exists :

> "message": "Field \"startsWith\" is not defined by type
>   StringQueryOperatorInput."

Is there a way to filter using prefix matching with graphQL ?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you got `fields` inside `node`? If so you should show us your schema (found in `http://localhost:8000/___graphql`), for example:

[image]

Anyway, I guess you want to query `fileAbsolutePath`:

```
query tagListQuery($prefix: String, $skip: Int!, $limit: Int!) {
  allMarkdownRemark(sort: {order: DESC, fields: [frontmatter___date]}, fileAbsolutePath: {regex: $prefix}}, limit: $limit, skip: $skip) {
    edges {
      node {
        id
        frontmatter {
          title
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you want to add `startWith` etc, you need to [customize the schema](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/schema-customization/).

Comment: regexp does the trick but is not really pretty to use... So there's no startsWith or beginsWith operator in graphQL or a way to extend graphQL with custom functions for filtering ?

Comment: It is not the default, you need to customize it https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/schema-customization/.